# What is the difference between "multiset<int, greater<int> > ms1" and "multiset<int> ms2(greater<int>())"

Tags: c++, multiset

In my opinion, they are the same. But in Visual Studio 2015, they are definitely different.

```
//Ok, work properly
multiset<int, greater<int> > ms1;
ms1.insert(10);
ms1.insert(20);

//error, why?
multiset<int> ms2(greater<int>());
ms2.insert(30);
ms2.insert(40);
```

I don’t know why?

Comment: No they're not the same. What gave you the idea that they are the same?

Comment: No answers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)?

Comment: @user0042: Not really, no. This question is about a lack of understanding of the difference between template arguments and function/constructor arguments. It's a core language question. It's not really about `std::multiset`, that's just the toy he happened to be playing with when this misunderstanding manifested itself.

Comment: `std::multiset` takes its first template parameter as a type and the second one as a compara function. You cannot put the compare function in the constructor arguments. Do you understand what a constructor is? That might give you a good hint on why this is really strange looking and should not be confused

Comment: @Benjamin You're probably right.

Comment: @Fureeish: Actually, the second template parameter is also a type. It is the type of the comparison functor which you want your multiset to use. And there is a constructor which takes a function object of that type. The only thing wrong with his second example is that the function object he is passing is not of the correct type. If he passed `less<int>()`, it would work.

Comment: Ahh, did not catch that. Thank you. I will leave my previous, incorrect comment since some other people might also have misunderstood that part and this is a good explanation

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For your first example:**

```
multiset<int, greater<int> > ms1;
```

This says that `ms1` is a `std::multiset`, storing `int`, and using a comparison functor of the type `std::greater<int>`. You've left out constructor arguments, so the instance of the functor is a default constructed one, exactly as if you had passed `std::greater<int>{}`, like this:

```
multiset<int, greater<int> > ms1(greater<int>{});
```

**In your second example:**

```
multiset<int> ms2(greater<int>());
```

This one is a bit tricky. There are 2 problems here. The first one relates to what is called "The Most Vexing Parse". It has been answered many times, so I will simply link to one of those answers. [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

So let's assume you understand that, and modify your code accordingly to this:

```
multiset<int> ms2(greater<int>{});
// or this
multiset<int> ms2((greater<int>()));
```

In this case, you've left out the type of the comparison functor, and gone with the default. The default is `std::less<int>`. So the above line is equivalent to this:

```
multiset<int, std::less<int> > ms2(greater<int>{});
```

What that says is that `ms2` is a `std::multiset`, storing `int`, and using a comparison functor of type `std::less<int>`. You are then passing an instance of `std::greater<int>` to the constructor. `std::less<int>` and `std::greater<int>` are different types. You can't pass an instance of one to a function that is expecting an instance of the other.

Comment: @Tango Xiao: I forgot about one problem, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @TangoXiao: See above comment. In summary, try `multiset<int, greater<int> > ms3(greater<int>{});`

Comment: Your answer is terrific. I understand. Thank you very much.